# Compile programs on multicore or distributed system

Tags: linux, makefile

Is there any software available in linux which compiles a source code containing large number of files parallely on either multicore or distributed systems. Libraries like gcc or xserver takes very time for compilation on unicore/dual machine and most of the times it is frustrating when you need lot of recompilation. Is there any technique for compiling such source code parallely ?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/414714/compiling-with-g-using-multiple-cores

Answer (score 31, accepted):

On distributed-memory systems, you can use [distcc](http://distcc.samba.org/) to farm out compile jobs to other machines.  This takes a little bit of setup, but it can really speed up your build if you happen to have some extra machines around.

On shared-memory multicore systems, you can just use [`make -j`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Parallel), which will try to spawn build jobs based on the dependencies in your makefiles.  You can run like this:

```
$ make -j
```

which will impose no limit on the number of jobs spawned, or you can run with an integer parameter:

```
$ make -j8
```

which will limit the number of concurrent build jobs.  Here, the limit is 8 concurrent jobs.  Usually you want this to be something close to the number of cores on your system.

Comment: AFAIK there are two schools on the "number of jobs". One being n+1 and the other 2n, where n is the number of cores. The rationale of both is that there is always a thread waiting once one gets completed... Personally, I have not seen real difference whether I put -j5 or -j8 on a quadcore

Comment: I also haven't seen much benefit from either n+1 or 2n on multicores, but then I haven't seen much of a decrease in performance from those either.  I'm suspicious that you don't get all the benefit you could out of those options b/c make doesn't set affinity for cores or sockets, but I haven't really tested this (I haven't even checked if make sets affinity, but I bet it doesn't).

Comment: Building is often IO bound. Lots of small files to work on means moving a lot of data to and from the disk... Plus forks are inexpensive on linux, but they *do* cost something, which contributes to the non-scaling. Finally, recursive make and other poor makefile practices can steal *a lot*.

Answer (score 4):

[ccache](http://ccache.samba.org/) can be used too to speed up compilation process

Comment: ccache only really benefits when you often need to rebuild identical artifacts, and if you do need to do that, your build system is defect to begin with.

Answer (score 3):

GNU make (the standard make installed on Linux systems) supports parallel command execution - take a look at http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Parallel