# Linking to PCL and OpenCV takes ages; a way to accelerate the process?

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm working with point cloud library (PCL) and OpenCV in order to process some point cloud data. The test program is very small, just creating a point cloud and converting it. Nothing fancy.

Build system is `cmake 3.13`.

The binary links to `PCL_LIBRARIES` and `OpenCV_LIBRARIES`. That step is taking ages (i.e. multiple minutes) to finish every time I change something in my code.

Is there a way to accelerate the link step?

Comment: This is a very generic question: Possible ways are using dynamic instead of static linking, use Gold or lld instead of ld or Microsofts's linker, drop debug symbols.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Speed Up linking speed / Fast linking on linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695287/speed-up-linking-speed-fast-linking-on-linux)