# Is the lld linker a drop-in replacement for ld and gold?

Tags: linker, ld, lld, gold-linker

The [linker from the LLVM project](http://lld.llvm.org/) `lld` is currently developed with new features added week by week. Its developers promise that `lld` is faster than `ld`. How does it compete compared to `gold`?

Is lld a drop-in replacement for `ld`? With [gold there are some hoops to jump through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476093/replacing-ld-with-gold-any-experience).

Comment: With their new ELF lld they claim to link Clang twice as fast compared to gold, but the binary is bigger. Despite some features are missing, that looks promising. http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/llvm-commits/Week-of-Mon-20151005/304675.html

Comment: *With WIP patches to both lld and FreeBSD it is possible to link a working
base system kernel and userland.* Source: http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/llvm-dev/2016-August/103998.html

Answer (score 19, accepted):

One of the LLD developers, Rui Ueyama, looks back at the progress LLD did in 2016, see http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/llvm-dev/2016-December/107981.html.

- "Now I'm pretty sure that that [LLD] is going to be a serious (and better, in my opinion) alternative to the existing GNU linkers [..]."
- "LLD is now able to link most x86-64 userland programs."
- "The FreeBSD project and we are trying to make LLD the system default linker of the operating system, and except a few tricky programs such as the kernel or a bootloader, the linker works mostly fine." [Already achieved!](http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/llvm-dev/2017-January/108668.html)
- "LLD supports x86, x86-64, x32, AArch64, AMDGPU, ARM, PPC64 and MIPS32/64,
  though completeness varies."
- "[T]here are already a few systems that are using LLD as system
  linkers, such as CloudABI or Fuchsia. Chromium and Clang/LLVM itself has
  build options to use LLD to build them."

And, as a bonus:

- "LLD got faster [..] At the beginning of this year,
  LLD took about 16 seconds to produce a 1.5 GB clang (debug build)
  executable. Now, it takes about 14.5 seconds on single core and 8.5 seconds
  on 20 cores. ld.gold takes about 25 seconds and 20 seconds,
  respectively. [..] If you have a problem of too long link time, I'd recommend to try LLD."

**Update spring 2017** According to one of the developers "LLD/ELF is now ready for production use at least for x86-64 (and probably for AArch64 and MIPS).", see http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/llvm-dev/2017-March/111083.html
It also contains a brief description on how to make use of LLD.

Comment: gcc v9.3.0+ now support using lld via -fuse-ld=lld. xref: https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/commit/d69ac8b7f890f79560b11a3548fa39f3e7f8427e

Answer (score 6):

**The program itself claims compatibility goal, and seems to work fine on simple tests**

This design goal is claimed [on their website](https://lld.llvm.org/):

> LLD is a drop-in replacement for the GNU linkers that accepts the same command line arguments and linker scripts as GNU.

E.g. on Ubuntu 20.04 [I install](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/184014/whats-the-name-of-ubuntu-package-contains-llvm-linker-lld):

```
sudo apt install lld
lld --version
```

says:

```
LLD 10.0.0 (compatible with GNU linkers)
```

and I'm able to compile a C hello world with `-fuse-ld=lld`:

```
gcc -fuse-ld=lld -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -o hello.out hello.c
```

**Performance benchmark vs gold**

I'll document results soon at: [Replacing ld with gold - any experience?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476093/replacing-ld-with-gold-any-experience/53921263#53921263)

Answer (score 1):

FreeBSD / OpenBSD use lld as the system linker. FreeBSD does across all supported archs, for OpenBSD we do for all minus mips64 at the moment (amd64 arm i386 powerpc -- aarch64 powerpc64 riscv64 ports were from scratch and never used the BFD linker, but do use lld). We're building the whole OS and 99.9999% of the ports tree. I can count on one hand how many are left that do not.

It's definitely much faster for larger projects especially larger C++ projects like Chrome, Firefox, Thunderbird, KDE, etc. Also lower memory utilization which can be problematic on 32-bit archs.