# Gcc collect2: fatal error: cannot find 'ld'

Tags: c, gcc, cross-compiling, ubuntu-15.10

I'm going through the tutorial on making an OS on http://wiki.osdev.org/Bare_Bones. When I try to link boot.o and kernel.o using this command: **i686-elf-gcc -T linker.ld -o myos.bin -ffreestanding -O2 -nostdlib boot.o kernel.o -lgcc** , I just get this error:

```
collect2: fatal error: cannot find 'ld'
compilation terminated.
```

I just installed fresh Ubuntu 15.10 that with *gcc-5.2.1* and *binutils-2.25.1* .
I have searched the internet for answers but nothing helped.

Comment: When linking, use the linker directly instead of calling the GCC front-end program. I.e. `i686-elf-ld` instead.

Comment: it might help to add "-v" flag to gcc command-line to see all paths.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg When I try `i686-elf-ld` command, it says it cannot find command. Any other suggestions?
@max630 It says this:
COLLECT_GCC=i686-elf-gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=$HOME/opt/cross/libexec/gcc/i686-elf/5.2.0/lto-wrapper
Target: i686-elf
Configured with: ../gcc-5.2.0/configure --target=i686-elf --prefix=$HOME/opt/cross --disable-nls --enable-languages=c,c++ --without-headers
Thread model: single
gcc version 5.2.0 (GCC) 

So, what exactly am I trying to see?

Comment: You have built a binutils package for the cross-compilation target? And installed it at the same location as the compiler?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg After I found collect2 program source I went through it and I don't think that source and program output match. Any ideas?

Comment: I have a similar problem with an ARM toolchain. Maybe it is the whole gold vs bfd linker thing. See [this SO question on the gold linker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476093/replacing-ld-with-gold-any-experience).

In the accepted answer, it is mentioned the gold linker has problems linking Linux kernel stuff. Your kernel isn't Linux obviously but it may be related. Try `-fuse-ld=bfd` when calling gcc to change to the bfd linker.

Comment: In case anyone stumbles upon this and is instead using a clang toolchain, I've been able to fix this problem by adding my toolchain to `PATH`. If you add `-debug` flag to the lowest `collect2` invocation, I saw that it was not actually looking for the binary `ld`, but instead a bunch of other ld-like names (`real-ld`, `collect-ld`, `ld.lld`, etc.) It just so happens that I wanted to use `ld.lld` provided in my toolchain, so adding it to the search PATH allowed collect2 to use my toolchain's ld.lld.

Answer (score 5):

I also got once the same error during a pentest while I was trying to compile my exploit on the victim server.

In my case, the directory where the "ld" program was located had not been defined in the PATH environment variable, so I simply added it.

**eg**. `export PATH=$PATH:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin`

Answer (score 2):

I tried to install the following packages, and it works for me.

```
sudo zypper install binutils binutils-devel binutils-gold
```

Comment: How is `zypper` relative to the question?

Comment: Fixes cargo-afl for me. Somehow, cargo-afl managed to invoke gcc in some way that made it not find ld. That despite Gcc working fine, and the binary I'm trying to fuzz doesn't even have any C dependencies. @273K, Zypper is OpenSuse's package manager. Debian users would translate zypper to apt and devel to dev. For once, it wasn't me that had to translate an apt command to a zypper command.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error while hacking a remote machine and trying to use gcc to compile an exploit on the victim machine.

I simply copied the program `ld` to `/tmp/`, the working directory where i was compiling my exploit `exploit.c` by  running 
`cp /usr/bin/ld /tmp/ld` 
followed by the original gcc compile command and the compile worked.

Comment: After reverting the (shared) Virtual Machine and trying this again, strangely it didn't work. Bizarre...

Comment: It isn't Bizarre, the `tmp` by default is not in the environmental path. Someone would of used `export PATH=$PATH+:/tmp` which then lets the OS find your binary.

Answer (score 0):

I searched a lot to fix this issue and nothing worked but lastly i uninstalled MinGw and reinstalled it then did edited the environment variables again and then uninstalled and reinstalled vs code extensions then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Today I had your same error about `ld` missing command.

First of all I install build-essential package (debian) for my arm64 architecture.

Then I create a symbolic link to /usr/bin/lld-11 file:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/lld-11 /usr/bin/ld
```

Now my rust environment works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

remove `-g -O2` and try again, if works for me at CGO

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was with LDFLAGS env variable set for another linker (-fuse-ld=lld).
Solution was to unset variable:

```
unset LDFLAGS
```