# Can gcc use multiple cores when linking?

Tags: gcc, linker

So when compiling tons of source files with GCC one can use -j to use all available cores. But what about the linker? Is there a similar option to speed up linking or does GCC not support multi-threading? In some larger projects it can really take a while ... (... and I hate to wait!)

**Edit:** Thanks for pointing out that -j is a option for make and not gcc/g++. But this does not answer my question! I would like to know if gcc can use multi threading while *linking* a program!

Comment: You might be interested in distcc http://distcc.org/ which will allow you to distribute compiles over several machines in a network.

Comment: @Jon: I am not interested in parallel compilation but in parallel linking!

Comment: Why did this question get downvoted? God knows gnu linker is dog slow and finding some way to make it link faster would only improve the build cycle.

Comment: Linking is not an obviously parallel task. Note that you can sometimes reduce the work of the linker using visibility attributes and/or the -fvisibility gcc option.

Comment: Not about gnu but finally Apple did a lot to speedup their linker and even developed a new library format in 2023. Remebmer that Apple is not using llvm linker but their own

Answer (score 14):

Try [gold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gold_%28linker%29), which was developed by Ian Lance Taylor et al. from Google and released as part of GNU binutils package.

From Wikipedia:

> The motivation for writing gold was to make a linker that is faster than the GNU linker, especially for large applications coded in C++

I must admit I haven't tried it myself yet but it's mentioned on [WebKitGTK project](https://trac.webkit.org/wiki/WebKitGTK/SpeedUpBuild) webpage.

For more information see an article written by the author of gold: [A New ELF Linker](http://research.google.com/pubs/archive/34417.pdf).

More importantly, see the work on incremental / parallel / concurrent linking by Sander Mathijs van Veen titled [Concurrent Linking with the GNU Gold Linker](http://smvv.kompiler.org/gold.pdf) and the bibliography therein.

Comment: It must be stressed that `gold` does not use multithreading unless you pass `gcc -Wl,--threads -Wl,--thread-count,$(nproc)`.

Answer (score 14):

[lld](https://lld.llvm.org/), the linker developed by the LLVM project, will use multiple cores by default. I have also found it to be about 2x faster than gold running with multiple threads (`-Wl,--threads -Wl,--thread-count,xxx`)

Comment: I reproduced the LLD 2x faster than gold with a precise benchmark described at https://stackoverflow.com/a/64128746/895245

Answer (score 7):

In 2022 the [mold linker](https://github.com/rui314/mold) is another great option.

It is the fastest linker available for ELF targets and has the most aggressive parallelism.

Answer (score 5):

The `-j` option you are referring to is handled by `make` not `gcc`.

Using `make -j n` asks `make` to run the actions in the `Makefile` with multiple parallel process (Replace `n` with a number. In the case of `make -j 2` it's `2` process).

Make will handle most synchronization tasks well when doing parallel builds.

Answer (score 4):

At [Replacing ld with gold - any experience?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476093/replacing-ld-with-gold-any-experience/53921263#53921263) I have benchmarked LD vs gold vs LLVM LLD on a minimal synthetic benchmark, and the time results clearly show that both gold and LLVM LLD are capable of parallel linking according to `time`, e.g.:

```
nogold:  wall=4.35s user=3.45s system=0.88s 876820kB
gold:    wall=1.35s user=1.72s system=0.46s 739760kB
lld:     wall=0.73s user=1.20s system=0.24s 625208kB
```

We know that parallel link was used because the [`wall` time was smaller than the `user` time in both of those CPUs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/556405/what-do-real-user-and-sys-mean-in-the-output-of-time1/53937376#53937376)

Those benchmarks also reproduce Martin Richtarsky's 2x faster LLVM LLD link times.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two options for those on CMake (tested on 3.16.3):

- Switch to [gold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gold_%28linker%29) linker, enable multi-threading (set to number of system cores):

```
find_program(GNU_GOLD_PROGRAM gold)
if (GNU_GOLD_PROGRAM)
    include(ProcessorCount)
    ProcessorCount(HOST_PROC_COUNT)
    add_link_options("-fuse-ld=gold;LINKER:--threads,--thread-count=${HOST_PROC_COUNT}")
endif(GNU_GOLD_PROGRAM)
```

- Switch to [lld](https://lld.llvm.org/) linker (works in multi-threading mode by default):

```
find_program(LLD_PROGRAM lld)
if(LLD_PROGRAM)
    add_link_options("-fuse-ld=lld")
endif(LLD_PROGRAM)
```

More complete example: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70389855/7598851)

Note: if you receive the error message "ld.lld: error: unable to find library ..." you may need to add the list of library directories in a link_directories call like so:

```
find_program(LLD_PROGRAM lld)
if(LLD_PROGRAM)
    add_link_options("-fuse-ld=lld")
    link_directories(/usr/lib64 /usr/local/lib64)
endif(LLD_PROGRAM)
```