# distributed MAKE

Tags: makefile, distributed

I had a MAKE compilation process that took around 1 hour to complete earlier. I used the -j command and was able to reduce it to 40 mins. What I observed is that the CPU utilization was high and my mentor suggested me to distribute the jobs on different SERVERS or machines available with our organization. I read about distcc but it can be used for c code only and we have a mix of c and java code. Kindly suggest me an appropriate tool to look for and which is the easiest to install and deploy as I am the only one working on this project.

Specifications - platform - solaris-sparc and x86 also

Thank you 
Ankit

Comment: If you use distcc, Make will distribute the C jobs to different servers while compiling the java locally. Is that not fast enough?

Answer (score 4):

[ElectricAccelerator](http://www.electric-cloud.com/products/electricaccelerator.php), a commercial product from Electric Cloud, is a drop-in replacement for GNU make that accelerates make-based builds by distributing the work to a cluster of computers.  It can also distribute and parallelize ant-based builds.  Accelerator uses a different mechanism than distcc so it is not tied to any particular toolchain or development language.

Disclaimer: I'm the architect and lead developer of ElectricAccelerator.

Comment: thank you for the answer. But i am actually looking for a freeware to work on. I read about electric accelerator earlier also and found it really helpful but it was a paid utility.

Answer (score 3):

Check out DistCC:

http://distcc.samba.org/

Works for both solaris-sparc and x86.

Good Luck!

Comment: distcc is used for C code only !!! we have java code as well. Presently we use make for the c code and call ant for java within it !! can u tell me if i can do the same while using distcc !!

Answer (score 1):

You can also hand-craft a solution.  Suppose you build four libraries, and have four servers.  Build on library on each server, using remote execution commands.

This is just one simple example, of course, to give you the idea.

Answer (score 1):

besides distcc,

- dmake is said to do what you call for: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19422-01/819-
  3697/dmake.html
- DMS http://www.nongnu.org/dms/faq.html also exists

See also ccache which speeds up compilation.