# Using xargs command and two move commands following it

Tags: bash, xargs

OS: aix
shell: bsh

Hi, ppl

I have two types of files, one type ends with **.pdf.marker** and the other ends with **.pdf**

There should be always a pair with the same name (only the extensions are different).

When I move a **.pdf.marker** file I must also move its corresponding **.pdf** file.

I tried something like this:

```
find ${INPUT_LOCATION}/ -name "*.pdf.marker" | xargs -I file mv file ${OUTPUT_LOCATION}/. mv $(basename file .marker) ${OUTPUT_LOCATION}/.
```

Then I read this: [xargs with multiple commands as argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6958689/xargs-with-multiple-commands-as-arguments)
and tried something like this:

```
find ${INPUT_LOCATION}/ -name "*.pdf.marker" | xargs -I file {mv file ${OUTPUT_LOCATION}/.; mv $(basename file .marker) ${OUTPUT_LOCATION}/.;}
```

but it still didnt work.

I just need to execute 2 commands after xargs.

**EDIT**

Following the proposed answers I got i tried to put just 2 parameters into one move command
instead of two separate move commands following xargs.

```
find ${INPUT_LOCATION}/ -name "*.pdf.marker" | xargs -I file mv file $(basename file .marker) ${OUTPUT_LOCATION}/.
```

But now, the **.pdf.marker** is moved first, then when I try to remove the **.marker** from the filename to get the **.pdf** filename i get a warning no such file or directory.

Is there another way to get **.pdf** filename string?

**SOLUTION**

```
find ${INPUT_LOCATION} -name '*.pdf.marker' -exec sh -c 'mv $0 `dirname $0`/`basename $0 .marker` $1' {} ${OUTPUT_LOCATION} \;
```

Moved 200 000 files in cca. 25  min. without problems.

Thanks everyone who participated with their answers and a **big thanks** goes to you Nahuel Fouilleul!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this  (x option for debug)

```
find "${INPUT_LOCATION}" -name '*.pdf.marker' | xargs -i bash -cx 'pdf=`dirname {}`/`basename {} .marker`;[ -e "$pdf" ]&&{ mv {} "$pdf" "$0";}' "${OUTPUT_LOCATION}"
```

or shorter

```
find $INPUT_LOCATION -name '*.pdf.marker' | xargs -i bash -c 'mv ${0%.marker} $0 $1' {} $OUTPUT_LOCATION
```

or

```
find $INPUT_LOCATION -name '*.pdf.marker' -exec bash -c 'mv ${0%.marker} $0 $1' {} $OUTPUT_LOCATION \;
```

maybe more standard

```
find ${INPUT_LOCATION} -name '*.pdf.marker' -exec sh -c 'mv $0 `dirname $0`/`basename $0 .marker` $1' {} ${OUTPUT_LOCATION} \;
```

and for tests echo can be added

```
find ${INPUT_LOCATION} -name '*.pdf.marker' -exec sh -c 'echo mv $0 `dirname $0`/`basename $0 .marker` $1' {} ${OUTPUT_LOCATION} \;
```

Comment: Your middle answer did the trick for me. Thanks :) I just have one more question, perhaps you'll know; the script is running under **aix** and will be executed via **bsh**, will the ...xargs -i **bash** -c 'mv.... make problems? In my testing enviroment I have **bash** but on the production enviroment(which I'm forbidden to access) its **bsh**.

Comment: variable substitution ${VAR%pat} may not work with bsh so the first answer is more standard sh but maybe with -f instead of -e

Comment: the 4th(more standard version) says **find missing argument '-exec'**

Comment: Yes, it works quite good even for 25k files, but it doesn't use **xargs** anymore. I will probably use your version, but I must be cautious because when we used **ls** command in conjuction with a **for loop** without **xargs**  we got an error like Argument list too long for a large number of files cca. 15k

Comment: the problem with ls is the shell expansion of * this is not the case with find because the * is between quotes there is no shell expansion to see the difference `echo '*.pdf.marker'` and `echo *.pdf.marker`

Answer (score 3):

You could try something like the following:

```
find ${INPUT}/ -name "*.pdf" -exec mv '{}' '{}'.marker ${OUTPUT} \;
```

To test if the marker file exists you could use something like the following:

```
find ${INPUT}/ -name "*.pdf" -exec test -e '{}'.marker \; -exec mv '{}' '{}'.marker ${OUTPUT} \;
```

Comment: i am only allowed to move a **.pdf** file if the **.pdf.marker** file exist and only then. So I need to use the **basename** command on the **.pdf.marker** file

Comment: i updated my answer, now only the pdf files with a marker file will be moved.

Answer (score 1):

No need to use xargs:

```
for i in `find ${INPUT_LOCATION} -name \*.pdf`; do mv $i ${OUTPUT_LOCATION}; mv $i.marker ${OUTPUT_LOCATION}; done
```

Comment: I need xargs because **find** returns >30k filenames

Answer (score 0):

```
for f in *.pdf.marker; do
  if [ -e "${f%.marker}" ]; then
    mv "$f" "${f%.marker}" "$OUTPUT_LOCATION"
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have GNU Parallel installed:

```
find ${INPUT_LOCATION} -name '*.pdf.marker' | parallel mv {} {.} ${OUTPUT_LOCATION}
```

To learn more watch the intro videos: http://pi.dk/1