# How to control the placement of xargs parameters?

Tags: bash, xargs

I have a Bash script that takes an input folder with source code and an output directory as arguments. I want to be able to compile the files in the source folder and then send them to an output folder. The problem is that `xargs` adds the read source files at the end of the argument, where I would like the output folder to be added instead. How can I control the placement of the `xargs` arguments? This is what I want to do: `find $source -name '*.c' | xargs gcc <files> $output`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using xargs command and two move commands following it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11429234/using-xargs-command-and-two-move-commands-following-it)

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved using:

```
find $source -name '*.c' | xargs gcc -o $output
```

This specifies the output of `gcc` before giving it the list of source files.

This problem cannot be solved by changing the location of the xargs argument, as if you do:

```
find $source -name '*.c' | xargs -I source gcc source -o $output
```

What will run, assuming you get `source/a.c` and `source/b.c` returned from `find` is:

```
gcc source/a.c -o $output
gcc source/b.c -o $output
```

Which I do not believe is the outcome you are after.

Answer (score 1):

Use GNU Parallel:

```
find $source -name '*.c' | parallel gcc {} -o $output/{.}
```

Or if you want all the files in {}:

```
find $source -name '*.c' | parallel -Xj1 gcc {} -o $output
```

Learn more about GNU Parallel: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1

10 second installation:

```
wget pi.dk/3 -qO - | sh -x
```

Answer (score 0):

This task can also be solved using only Bash:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ $# -ne 2 ]; then
    echo "usage: $0 [srcdir] [bindir]"
    exit 1
fi

src_dir="${1%/}"
bin_dir="${2%/}"

for src in "$src_dir"/*.c; do
    bin="$(basename "${src%.c}")"
    gcc "$src" -o "$bin_dir/$bin"
done
```