# BASH - find specific folder with find and filter with regex

Tags: regex, bash

I have a folder containing many folders with subfolder (/...) with the following structre:

```
_30_photos/combined
_30_photos/singles
_47_foo.bar
_47_foo.bar/combined
_47_foo.bar/singles
_50_foobar
```

With the command `find . -type d -print | grep '_[0-9]*_'` all folder with the structure **** will be shown. But I have generate a regex which captures only the */combined folders:
`_[0-9]*_[a-z.]+/combined` but when I insert that to the find command, nothing will be printed.

The next step would be to create for each combined folder (somewhere on my hdd) a folder and copy the content of the combined folder to the new folder. The new folder name should be the same as the parent name of the subfolder e.g. _47_foo.bar. Could that be achieved with an xargs command after the search?

Comment: if you insert your regex into -regex option with find be aware that find matches the full path -> if you start from . then the regex MUST match ./whatever/come.here

Comment: This sounds suspiciously like an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).  mybecks, what are you *really* trying to achieve?

Comment: is it possible to tell find that it should search only inside this (or predefined) directory and of course in all subdirs

Comment: @mybecks ...but isn't that what you tell find with the very first argument

Comment: I had think that to, but realized that all folder with that naming are found (and deleted, I use that find command for deleting too)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With basic `grep` you will need to escape the `+`:

```
... | grep '_[0-9]*_[a-z.]\+/combined'
```

Or you can use the "extended regexp" version (`egrep` or `grep -E` [thanks chepner]) in which the `+` does not have to be escaped.

`xargs` may not be the most flexible way of doing the copying you describe above, as it is tricky to use with [multiple commands](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6958957/341459). You may find more flexibility with a while loop:

```
... | grep '_[0-9]*_[a-z.]\+/combined' | while read combined_dir; do 
    mkdir some_new_dir
    cp -r ${combined_dir} some_new_dir/
done
```

Have a look at [bash string manipulation](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) if you want a way to automate the name of `some_new_dir`.

Comment: if I do `echo $combined_dir` it prints out the whole path ./_00_foo.bar/combined. THis is okay. But now I want to copy the content of /combined to the main dir (_00_foo.bar). Therefore I used the following syntax inside the loop:`CURRENT_DIR=$(echo $combined_dir | grep "_[0-9]*_[a-z.]\+")` but I doesn't work :(

Answer (score 12):

You do not need grep:

```
find . -type d -regex ".*_[0-9]*_.*/combined"
```

For the rest:

```
find . -type d -regex "^\./.*_[0-9]*_.*/combined" | \
   sed 's!\./\(.*\)/combined$!& /somewhere/\1!'   | \
   xargs -n2 cp -r
```

Answer (score 1):

```
target_dir="your target dir"

find . -type d -regex ".*_[0-9]+_.*/combined" | \
  (while read s; do
     n=$(dirname "$s")
     cp -pr "$s" "$target_dir/${n#./}"
   done
  )
```

NOTE:

- this fails if you have linebreaks "\n" in your directory names
- this uses a subshell to not clutter your env - inside a script you don't need that
- changed the regex slightly: `[0-9]*` to `[0-9]+`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command:

```
find . -type d | grep -P "_[0-9]*_[a-z.]+/combined"
```