# Bash script how to execute a command from a variable

Tags: bash

I am trying to alter the Bash function below to execute each command argument. But when I run this script, the first echo works as intended, but the second echo that attempts to append to the *scratch.txt* file does not actually execute. It just gets echo'd into the prompt.

```
#!/bin/sh
clear

function each(){
  while read line; do
    for cmd in "$@"; do
      cmd=${cmd//%/$line}
      printf "%s\n" "$cmd"
      $cmd
    done
  done
}

# pipe in the text file and run both commands
# on each line of the file
cat scratch.txt | each 'echo %' 'echo -e "%" >> "scratch.txt"'

exit 0
```

How do I get the $cmd variable to execute as a command?

I found the original code from answer 2 here:
*[Running multiple commands with xargs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6958689/xargs-with-multiple-commands-as-argument)*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want `eval`.  It's evil.  Or at least, dangerous.  Read all about it at [BashFAQ #48](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048).

Comment: Re *"You want eval"*: Do you mean *"You don't want eval"*? Or *"You want eval, but"*? Or something else?