# xargs with multiple commands

Tags: bash, xargs

In the current directory, I'd like to print the filename and contents in it.
I can print filenames or contents separately by

```
find . | grep "file_for_print" | xargs echo
find . | grep "file_for_print" | xargs cat
```

but what I want is printing them together like this:

```
file1
line1 inside file1
line2 inside file1
file2
line1 inside file2
line2 inside file2
```

I read [xargs with multiple commands as argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6958689/xargs-with-multiple-commands-as-argument)
and tried

```
find . | grep "file_for_print" | xargs -I % sh -c 'echo; cat;'
```

but doesn't work.
I'm not familiar with xargs, so don't know what exactly "-I % sh -c" means.
could anyone help me? thank you!

Comment: try this ..... i think this should help , "find . | grep "file_for_print" | xargs more "

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To start with, there is virtually no difference between:

```
find . | grep "file_for_print" | xargs echo
```

and

```
find . -name "file_for_print*"
```

except that the second one will not match filenames like `this_is_not_the_file_for_print`, and it will print the filenames one per line. It will also be a lot faster, because it doesn't need to generate and print the entire recursive directory structure just in order for grep to toss most of it away.

```
find . -name "file_for_print*"
```

is actually exactly the same as

```
find . -name "file_for_print*" -print
```

where the `-print` action prints each matched filename followed by a newline. If you don't provide `find` with any actions, it assumes you wanted `-print`. But it has more tricks up its sleeve than that. For example:

```
find . -name "file_for_print*" -exec cat {} \;
```

The `-exec` action causes find to execute the following command, up to the `\;`, replacing `{}` with each matching file name.

`find` does not limit itself to a single action. You can tell it to do however many you want. So:

```
find . -name "file_for_print*" -print -exec cat {} \;
```

will probably do pretty well what you want.

For lots more information on this very useful utility, type:

```
man find
```

or

```
info find
```

and read all about It.

Comment: yeah find and xargs are pretty amazing.

Answer (score 31):

`find . | grep "file_for_print" | xargs -I % sh -c 'echo %; cat %;'` (OP was missing `%`s)

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for! Thank you!

Comment: happy to have been of help :-)

Comment: This solution works on linux, but not on macos (mojave).

Answer (score 14):

Since it's not been said yet: `-I %` tells xargs to replace '%' with the arguments in the command you give it. The `sh -c '...'` just means run  the commands `'...'` in a new shell.

So

```
xargs -I % sh -c 'echo %; cat %;'
```

will run `echo [filename]` followed by `cat [filename]` for every filename given to `xargs`. The echo and cat commands will be executed inside a different shell process but this usually doesn't matter. Your version didn't work because it was missing the `%` signs inside the command passed to `xargs`.

---

For what it's worth I would use this command to achieve the same thing:

```
find -name "*file_for_print*" | parallel 'echo {}; cat {};'
```

because it's simpler (`parallel` automatically uses `{}` as the substitution character and can take multiple commands by default).

Answer (score 2):

In this specific case, each command is executed for each individual file anyway, so there's no advantage in using xargs. You may just append -exec twice to your 'find':

```
find . -name "*file_for_print*" -exec echo {} \; -exec cat {} \;
```

In this case`-print` could be used instead of the first `echo` as pointed out by rici, but this example shows the ability to execute two arbitrary commands with a single `find`

Answer (score 0):

What about writing your own bash function?

```
#!/bin/bash

myFunction() {
    while read -r file; do
        echo "$file"
        cat "$file"
    done
}

find . -name "file_for_print*" | myFunction
```