# Linux bash - eval vs. sh -c

Tags: linux, bash, shell, eval, sh

I have been experimenting with some bash scripting and ran into a problem that I do not quite understand. I am trying to print out all my files in a directory and use the print out to show not only the name of the file, but also the size and last modified date. I can do that with the following command:

`ls | xargs -I '{}' sh -c 'echo "{}" $(stat -c "%y %s" "{}")'`

I got the the use of `sh -c` from this post: [xargs with multiple commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6958689/xargs-with-multiple-commands-as-argument) (first answer). I understand that the `sh -c` part is the command that's being executed, which reads in the string as a command. However, what I don't quite understand is why other commands won't work, such as `eval` in place of `sh -c`. For example:

`ls | xargs -I '{}' eval 'echo "{}" $(stat -c "%y %s' "{}")'`

Doesn't `eval` also take a string as an argument and then evaluate it? ([eval command in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11065077/eval-command-in-bash-and-its-typical-uses)) I get that I have a working command with the `sh -c`, but I would like to know why this command is different from `eval`.

Comment: `eval` is a shell built-in command; `xargs` expects an executable file.

Comment: Is that to say that when I use `sh -c`, it creates an executable file that is then passed to `xargs`?

Comment: The simple difference is that `sh -c 'stuff'` spawns a new process, does stuff, then the process goes away: `eval 'stuff'` does stuff in your *current shell*.

Comment: `sh` *is* an executable file, which executes the string passed by the `-c` argument as a shell command.

Comment: ...to reinforce @anubhava's answer -- see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs for some descriptions of why parsing `ls` output is inherently prone to breakage.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, because `sh` spawns in a new command shell, `xargs` will accept it as an argument? In the man page (http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?xargs), it states that the command `builds and executes command line from standard input`. Does this mean that it `eval` doesn't count as "standard input"?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: thanks for the link. I will keep that in mind in the future. As an added note, if I were to use `grep` in the pipe after the `ls` command, would that make things any better?

Comment: Even using `ls | grep "foobar"` is error prone for the same reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`xargs` can only run an external executable -- something which the operating system's `execv()` family of calls can execute. (Keep in mind that `xargs` itself is not part of your shell but an external program, and thus it has no access to the shell that started it).

The shell builtin `eval` is not an executable. Thus, `xargs` cannot run it. (By its nature, it invokes code in the current shell. `xargs` is not a shell, so it has no ability to interpret shell scripts, and there is no "current shell" when xargs is the active process).

`sh` is an executable (starting a new shell). Thus, `xargs` can start it, and it can be used in contexts where no current shell exists.

---

By the way -- you tagged this question `bash`, but `sh` is not `bash`. If you want to be able to run bash code under your shell invoked as a separate process, use `bash -c`, not `sh -c`; since `sh -c` starts a separate shell out-of-process, you can also get a different shell, at a different version, with different capabilities (and even if your `/bin/sh` is a symlink to `/bin/bash`, bash turns off some functionality when started as `sh`).

Comment: Thanks Charles. I think this provides the most clear and in-depth answer into my question.

Answer (score 4):

You don't really need `eval` or `sh -c` or `ls` parsing. Just use `stat`:

```
stat -c "%n %y %s" *
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It does remind me that I should look thoroughly through the different formatting options. However, it would be great if you could shed light on the difference between `sh -c` and `eval`.

Comment: @Zhouster See my comment to your question, but this is the code you want to use. Piping from `ls` and using `eval` are both signs that you are Doing It Wrong.

Comment: `eval` is a shell bulletin and `sh -c` lets you run a command line in a forked sub process however effectively both do the same things and both are risky if your command line is coming from not trusted source.

Comment: If this is for scripted use, better to use a format string like `%Y %s %n\0` -- that way once you read the mtime and the size, anything up to the next NUL character is part of the name (with no room for ambiguity, since NULs -- unlike spaces or newlines -- can't exist in names).

Answer (score 2):

`sh -c` summons a new shell while `eval` executes it on the current shell. Any changes in the environment inside the new shell does not affect the shell that called it.