# Allow to pass an argument on second line

Tags: bash, shell, unix, arguments

Is there any way I can have a bash file and pass an argument on a second line like this

```
sh -c
git status;
echo "hello world"
```

this is really ugly

```
sh -c "git status; echo "hello world""
```

I'm passing sh to another command so I can't just do:

```
git status;
echo "hello world"
```

even a way to do something like this would be nice

```
echo
"hello world"
```

essentially I need a way of not terminating on new line

looking for a prettier way of passing to commands to `xargs` here 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6958957/340688

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply quote it.  Quoted strings can extend over multiple lines.

```
sh -c '
git status
echo "hello world"'
```

You can play with indentation and placement of the quotation marks to find out what most closely meets your aesthetic expectations.

```
# Does this look nicer?
sh -c '
  git status
  echo "hello world"
'
```

If you want variable expansion to take place, you'd probably want to change double and single quotes.

```
dir=/src/project/
sh -c "
  cd $dir
  git status
  echo 'hello world'
"
```

Note that this becomes messy if you want more complex quoting (involving both, single and double quotes itself) in the `-c` argument.  Consider using heredoc syntax as suggested by [Srdjan Grubor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27451504/1392132) in this case.  Note however that it feeds the script to the shell via standard input, not as a command line parameter.

For your second example, simply escape the newline character.

```
echo \
  "hello world"
```

Be careful not to place any other spaces (or other characters, including comments) between the `\` and the end of the line.

Some people, including me, find code easier to read if those backslashes are all aligned at some fixed column.

```
echo                  \
  "hello"             \
  "happy"             \
  "fruit gum"         \
  "world"
```

Your editor might help you with this.

Answer (score 1):

```
sh << EOF
  git status
  echo "hello world"
EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

In a terminal

```
echo \
"hello world"
```

or

```
  sh -c \
    "git status; \
    echo "hello world""
```

Comment: Your second example treats `git` as the argument for `-c` and `status;`, `echo`, and `"hello world"` as additional positional arguments.