# Bash - how do i output line and then pipe line to another command side by side?

Tags: bash, xargs

Perhaps best explained with an example. I want to do this:

file:

```
one
two
three
```

command:

```
cat file | xargs -n1 show_square_of_stringed_number
```

output:

```
one one
two four 
three nine
```

`show_square_of_stringed_number two` just returns `four`, and can only accept one argument.

Not looking for the implementation of `show_square_of_stringed_number`, but simply how to echo the input to the pipe (two) alongside the output (four).

Wishing `xargs` had this feature built in. Can't do it with `tee <(show_square)` either because it operates on the entire list, not on a single row.

Comment: I think I might have asked this too soon, and found the answer already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6958689/xargs-with-multiple-commands-as-argument

Comment: `xargs -I {} -n1 bash -c 'printf "%s " {}; show_square_of_stringed_number {}'` EDIT: saw that duplicate already existed. So, this answer is effectively same as ones posted on earlier questions.

Comment: thank for answering still. you are correct, duplicate.