# Running multiple commands with xargs - for loop

Tags: bash, find, xargs

Based on the top answer in [Running multiple commands with xargs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6958689/running-multiple-commands-with-xargs) I'm trying to use find / xargs to work upon more files. Why the first file 1.txt is missing in for loop?

```
$ ls
1.txt  2.txt  3.txt

$ find . -name "*.txt" -print0 | xargs -0
./1.txt ./2.txt ./3.txt

$ find . -name "*.txt" -print0 | xargs -0 sh -c 'for arg do echo "$arg"; done'
./2.txt
./3.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you insist on using `xargs`? You can do the following as well.

```sh
while read -r file; do
    echo $file
done <<<$(find . -name "*.txt")
```

Because this is executed in the same shell, changing variables is possible in the loop. Otherwise you'll get a sub-shell in which that doesn't work.

Comment: When a filename has a newline in it, The filename is cut in two parts. That might have been the reason for `print0`.

Answer (score 0):

When you use your for-loop in a script `example.sh`, the call `example.sh var1 var2 var3` will put `var1` in the first argument, not `example.sh`.
When you want to process one file for each command, use the `xargs` option `-L`:

```
find . -name "*.txt" -print0 | xargs -0 -L1 sh -c 'echo "$0"'
# or for a simple case
find . -name "*.txt" -print0 | xargs -0 -L1 echo
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran across this while having the same issue.  You need the extra _ at the end as place holder 0 for xargs

```
$ find . -name "*.txt" -print0 | xargs -0 sh -c 'for arg do echo "$arg"; done' _
```