# Using xargs to run multiple commands

Tags: linux, bash, xargs

Using [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6958689/running-multiple-commands-with-xargs) as a starting point I am running the following in bash:

```
seq 1 5 | xargs -d $'\n' sh -c 'for arg do echo $arg; done'
```

**Expected output**

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

**Actual output**

```
2
3
4
5
```

i.e. is missing the first of the intended arguments.

Am probably being a tool, but wondering why this is.

Comment: That dupe question has no mention of `xargs` so how it is an exact dupe?

Comment: @anubhava You have a golden badge, you can reopen the question unilaterally if you didn't like the duplicate target, or add a better one. I don't think this question is really related to xargs though

Comment: I don't disagree that linked answer is related to this problem but here OP is asking `Using xargs to run multiple commands` and we already have an answer taking out `sh -c` from a proposed solution

Comment: @anubhava Well, go ahead and reopen it then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass some dummy value at position 0 to `sh` script like this:

```sh
seq 1 5 | xargs -d $'\n' sh -c 'for arg do echo $arg; done' _
1
2
3
4
5
```

Without passing `_` to `sh` script `1` is passed as `$0` whereas `for arg` loops through positional arguments starting with position `1` only.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe that'll teach me to stop ignoring stuff that makes no sense on first reading.

Comment: This is why you'll see `xargs sh -c '...' sh` on these kind of answers.

Answer (score 3):

In conclusion, do you want to list number or execute command by row?
Usually, use below command in bash.

```
seq 1 5 | xargs -n 1 -I {} echo {}
```

Output

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies with your inline bash code.

`seq 1 5 | xargs -n echo` produces the desired result. It can also be simplified to `seq 5 | xargs -n echo` because `seq` assumes the range starts at 1.