# How to find the files for a particular pattern and list the filenames according to the file modified timestamp

Tags: shell, unix

I have a requirement to identify the list of files ( from past 7 days) having particular pattern - say from large number of archive files and print the filenames according to their file modified timestamp.

Any thoughts?

```bash
find /Source -name "TEST\_\*" -mtime -7 -print0| xargs -0 grep -l "pattern"
```

Got the filenames - need it to be sorted by its file modified timestamp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use `stat -c %Y` or `stat -c %y`

the whole statement could look like:

```
find /Source -name "TEST\_\*" -mtime -7 -print0| xargs -0 -i  sh -c 'echo "$(stat -c %y "{}") {}"' | sort -rn
```

or

```
find /Source -name "TEST\_\*" -mtime -7 -print0| xargs -0 -i  sh -c 'echo "$(stat -c %Y "{}") {}"' | sort -rn
```

help for xargs i found here: [Running multiple commands with xargs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6958689/running-multiple-commands-with-xargs)

from man stat :

```
  %y   time of last data modification, human-readable
  %Y   time of last data modification, seconds since Epoch
```