# Make -j (multiple jobs) with number specified doesn't work in QNX

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, qnx

From various sources ([like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/414714/compiling-with-g-using-multiple-cores?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)) state that you can parallelise your build jobs with:

```
make -j n
```

where `n` is the number of jobs. In QNX 6.5.0 with GNU Make 3.81
I noticed that the number doesnt seem to work. If i call `make -j` (no number) a huge number of compilers will be started and the processors will be used fully:

```
CPU states: 80.5% user, 5.0% kernel
CPU  0 Idle: 15.2%
CPU  1 Idle: 13.2%
CPU  2 Idle: 14.7%
Memory: 0 total, 281M avail, page size 4K

      PID   TID PRI STATE    HH:MM:SS    CPU  COMMAND
     8200     2  21 Rcv       0:00:17  12.02% devb-eide
 43565087     1  10 Rdy       0:00:00  11.38% make
 43819103     1  10 Rply      0:00:00   3.01% cmake
 43716678     1  10 Rply      0:00:00   2.80% cmake
 43671611     1  10 Rply      0:00:00   1.87% make
 43589671     1  10 Rply      0:00:00   1.73% make
 43569184     1  10 Rply      0:00:00   1.73% make
 43573283     1  10 Rply      0:00:00   1.46% make
 43667514     1  10 Rply      0:00:00   1.28% make
 43839590     1  10 Send      0:00:00   1.10% cmake
```

Unfortunately when i use `make -j` having the huge number of concurrent builds means that my limited VM quickly runs out of memory.

But if I add a number (eg. `make -j 4`, which corresponds to the number of cores in my VM) then it will only ever start 1 process. This also occurs with the following variants:

```
make -j4
make -j 4
make --jobs=4
make --jobs 4
```

As well as with some other processor numbers (2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8).

**Why doesnt `make -j` with a specified number work in QNX?**

Comment: How is that related to c++?

Comment: What implementation of `make` are you using? What version of that implementation?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Added to the quest, and it is GNU Make 3.81

Comment: You are free to remove makefile tag if it is unrelated, but I would say it is much more related than c++

Comment: did you try to create simple makefile with echo command without any dependency and run `make -j` on it? Did you try to run `mke -j4` (without space)? Did you try to use full form `make --jobs=4` ? Did you check that you do not have alias for `make`?

Comment: @Slava, I updated the question with more information of what i have tried. I will try the simple makefile now. I have no make aliases.

Comment: I have no access to QNX but the last time I used it (>10 years ago) it had a fairly robust POSIX interface, so I have no idea why -j N would not work.  I assume that since you're using such an old version you didn't build it yourself.  Maybe the person who built it disabled the jobserver.  I recommend you obtain the latest GNU make version source file and try to compile it yourself.  When you run configure, see what it says about jobserver support.

Comment: @MadScientist But it can create multiple jobs when no number is supplied. Do you think the build configuration could have caused behaviour like this?

Comment: make uses entirely different ways of handling multiple jobs when you give a number with -j and when you give no number.  With `-j` by itself you are asking for "infinite parallelism" so make doesn't count the number of jobs running or track them.  And since 2 * infinity == infinity, all sub-makes also run infinite jobs and there's no tracking of jobs between recursive invocations of make.  When you use `-jN` all those extra capabilities come into play.  Using `-j` with no maximum is intended to be used in conjunction with `-l` (limit jobs based on system load).

Comment: @MadScientist Makes sense. Thanks for the advice, i will look into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `make` version used in the system must have been compiled using a configure item that disabled the `-j` task engine. Recompiling GNU Make 3.81 and 4.2 yielded a binary that can successfully use the `-j` switch with a number.